# Avoid other external sites copying SO questions?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of sites copying SO questions & answers in the Internet (easily found in Google search results). I think it is done by robots. Is there anything SO can do to stop the robots to "steal" the contents from Stack Overflow ?